# Safety/vulnerability of using Codeigniter query builder custom where string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sanitization

I'm working on a Codeigniter 2 project that is just not feasible to upgrade to v.3. So far I've run into a dilemma when using query builder, especially when I need to make a more complex query. CI v.3 handles it quite nicely by using ->group_start() and ->group_end(), but CI v.2 doesn't have it.
Now, my dilemma is the following: Is it safe to just use custom where query?

```
$this->db->where("name='$name' AND status='boss' OR status='active'");
```

Does the query builder sanitize it enough or should I employ additional sanitization (the third parameter is left as default - true)?

** **UPDATE** **

I did not write precisely which complex query I need this for. Somewhere along this logic:

A=1 && B=2 && C=3 && (D=10 || E=20 || F=30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a correct implementation of your query would be

```
$this->db
    ->where('name',$name)
    ->group_start()
        ->where('status','boss')
        ->or_where('status','active')
    ->group_end();
```

**edit for Codeigniter 2**

```
$this->db
    ->where('name',$name)
    ->where('(status','boss')
    ->or_where('status',$this->db->escape('active').')',false);
```

Comment: The "group_start()" and "group_end()" is a great update in version 3, but as I've noted - I'm working in version 2 and it is not feasible to upgrade to version 3.

Comment: i added a possible solution for Version 2 now

Comment: This pretty much challenged how I view query builder (putting starting parenthesis in one line and the finishing one in the other one), I've tested it and it works just the way you've described it would.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

> Note: All values passed to this function are escaped automatically,
>   producing safer queries.

This I'm presuming is if you use it properly and not directly insert the vars like your thinking.

So I would do it like (If I used CI :/)

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where("(status='boss' OR status='active')", NULL, FALSE);
```

..ugly

Comment: But, wouldn't it produce query like: ...`WHERE name = 'JOE' OR status = 'boss' OR status = 'active';`I've forgot to mention why I need this - for complex queries (not just simple like the one above). In cases when I need to get something like this: (A & B) || (C & D).

Comment: @agapetos Updated, there are ways to integrate any complex query but it just means its going to take longer to dissect your normal query into the query builder. I love [RedBean](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying), it makes it just too easy.

Comment: I agree it looks ugly, but I still think that custom where() function is still more secure than query() (since, I guess, inside the where() function you can't do anything else besides selecting).
There are some other solutions that necessitate use of FALSE as the third argument, but I opt not to use it if there are other options. I also don't know if use of FALSE as third argument + $this->db->escape() is safer than custom where() function.

Answer (score 1):

I use CI but skip their query builder and use PDO. You can still put all your settings in `/config/database.php` and use them directly.

```
 class SomeModel_model extends CI_Model {

   protected $pdo;

   public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();

   $this->load->database();

   $opt = array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
   );

   $this->pdo = new PDO($this->db->dsn, $this->db->username, $this->db->password, $opt);

   }
```

And then a select like...

```
  // $this->db->where("name='$name' AND status='boss' OR status='active'");

  $sql = "SELECT * from myTable where name = :name and (status = 'boss' OR status = 'active')';

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->execute(['name' => $name]);

  $results = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: This is more of a suggestion not an answer to his question though.

Answer (score 1):

Query builder only escapes data passed to it directly and not through assignment in a  string.

If you want to be safe simply escape the variables before inputting them like so:

`$var1 = $this->db->escape_str($data)`

And now it's relatively safe for your query.

[Documentation of this here.](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html)